# Django-cronjob не отрабатывает на сервере

Tags: django

Написал простой cronjob для django. залил на сервер. Однако при после запуска сервере он не выполняется.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ## make jobs for django
    'django_crontab',
    ...
]
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'myproject.cron.MyCronJob')
]
```

cron.py

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from myapp.models import TestModel
import time
import csv


t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H_%M_%S", t)

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'myproject.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        query_data = str(TestModel.objects.all().values())
        with open(f'iinvoc{current_time}.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([query_data])
        return print(query_data)
```

А если использовать следующею команду, то джоб отрабатывает.

```
python manage.py runcrons --force
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка ?